# How to maintain the scroll position of scroll bar in listbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

> After Submitting the form the scroll goes up how will retain the
>   position of the scroll ?  this code does not work  can anyone help thank you in advance or advice to do.

```
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>

<style>
        .container {
            border:2px solid #ccc;
            width:600px;
            height: 1000px;
            overflow-y: scroll;
        }
        </style>

<script>
var scrollPos=$("form").scrollTop();
onclick="javascript: submit()

</script>
<form method="post" name="form">

    <div id="Html2" style="position:absolute;left:0x;top:60px;width:250px;height:100px;z-index:12" class="container">
        <input onclick="javascript: submit()" type="checkbox">Checkbox1
        <br>
        <input onclick="javascript: submit()" type="checkbox">Checkbox1
        <br>
        <input onclick="javascript: submit()" type="checkbox">Checkbox1
        <br>
        <input onclick="javascript: submit()" type="checkbox">Checkbox1
        <br>
        <input onclick="javascript: submit()" type="checkbox">Checkbox1
        <br>
        <input onclick="javascript: submit()" type="checkbox">Checkbox1
        <br>

    <script>    $("form").scrollTop(scrollPos);</script>

    </div>
</form>


</script>
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it in pure Javascript:

```
var elem = document.querySelector(".container");
elem.onscroll = function () {
    sessionStorage.setItem('scroll', elem.scrollTop);
};

if (sessionStorage.getItem('scroll') != null) {
    elem.scrollTop = parseInt(sessionStorage.getItem('scroll'));
}
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/61nay9Lg/)

Comment: didnt show any error but in js fiddle it show CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.
More information is available with DEBUG=True.

Comment: @MaricarManlulu, of course it will, since the JSFiddle has no form to post the data to, so u get that page. But the point is when you reload the page, or re-run the fiddle,  since you are still using the same browser tab, the scrollbar position is maintained.

Comment: its still the scrollbar going upward after submitting. it no maintained

Comment: So you mean, in the jsfiddle, when you scroll down the list, click a checkbox to submit, then _Run_ the jsfiddle again, you dont see teh scroll bar down to where you scrolled?

Comment: i copy what you have done in my IDE and run it the listbox scroll did not return to previous location after submitting

Answer (score -1):

You can save the position of scroll first. And then retain it again.

```
var scrollPos=$("form").scrollTop();

//submit code goes here

$("form").scrollTop(scrollPos);
```

Comment: The OP did not tag JQuery in the question :)

Comment: @AhsN He actually did.

Comment: Can you try this code  : `var scrollPos;

$(".container").scroll(function (){
    scrollPos=$(".container").scrollTop();
});


$("form").submit(function (){
 $(".container").scrollTop(scrollPos);
});`

Comment: Line `$(".container").scrollTop(scrollPos);` should be in your submit function.

Comment: Can you please post some fiddle or anything so that we can try our code ?